# l3build not working

Tags: l3build

When I try to run `l3build doc`, I get:

```
l3build doc
/Library/TeX/texbin/l3build: line 1: --[[: command not found
/Library/TeX/texbin/l3build: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Library/TeX/texbin/l3build: line 3: `File l3build.lua Copyright (C) 2014-2022 The LaTeX Project'
```

I know this would be caused by some simple configuration problem, but I'm lost.

I'm using a default zsh on my Mac, and using "TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2023".

I believe `l3build` is a Lua file and the problem stems from my shell not being able to run a lua file, but `texlua pathtol3build` does not seem like a correct way to invoke it...

Comment: There was a transient issue with `l3build` on *nix platforms - please update and the issue should be solved

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you! It works like charm now :)

Comment: So the problem was the missing shebang to the `texlua` in the `l3build` Lua script!

Comment: Indeed - as this was a very brief issue that is fixed by update, we typically close rather than answer such questions

Comment: @JosephWright Should I vote to close due to "A community-specific reason"?